# asp ERROR MESSAGE

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

How I can solve this error message

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error
>   '800a01a8'  Object required: 'lUATRef'
>
> /cmgtest/transaction/viewPCReqForm.asp,
>   line 284

this is some source code that I wrote below

```
function checkUATReq(aUATRef) 
    Dim correctness,lUATRef,uatRef 
    correctness = False 
    lUATRef = aUATRef 
    uatRef = lUATRef.Substring(1,2) 
    rwriteln uatRef 
    'sqlCheckUATReq = "select * from PC_DETAIL where ID ='"&uatReqRef&"'" 
    'rwriteln uatReqRef 
End function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your function isn't getting a parameter passed to it. Check whether aUATRef is getting initialized.

Comment: aUATRef is already initialized. It's still occur same message.

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript, Strings aren't objects.  You should use the [`Mid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to get a portion of a string:

```
uatRef = Mid(IUATRef, 1, 2)
```